# Time series books/resources that are unified with linear regression and machine learning?

Tags: regression, time-series, references

I know Shumway's book is pretty good, but reading it is like reading a whole new field of statistics.  For example, white noise as opposed to just error term.  Xt and Zt instead of Y and X, forecasting instead of predicting, etc...  Is there a good book or resource out there the bridges time series analysis with regular linear regression and/or machine learning.  In other words, they use the same or similar terminology and bridges the two so that I can see how time series is just linear regression concepts adapted to work with time series data.  Or how we can use ML techniques on time series problems.  For example, now that our data are not independent, what assumptions of linear regression fail and how does time series techniques adjust for it.

Thanks